# ResponseEntity got null body when using DeferredResult

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot 1.4.4 to create an async RESTful api. Everything works fine except when request is successfully processed, DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> always has null body and 200 OK status code even though i explicitly set string value to the result object.The code looks like this:

RestController impl:

```
 @Async
  public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> parseWithLongDelay(    
     @RequestBody MyRequestObject req){
     DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
     :
     :
     result.setResult(new ResponseEntity<String>("That big zip file successfully parsed.", HttpStatus.OK));
     return result;
  }
```

Client side:

```
 @Test
 public void test(){
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> futureEntity = new AsyncRestTemplate().postForEntity(url, requestEntity,
    String.class);
    futureEntity.addCallback(new MyFutureCallback());
    :
  }
  class MyFutureCallback implements ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> entity) {
   String body = entity.getBody();
   log.info("response content: " + body);
   //always get null body, there is no server side exception or error
   //when callback happens
 }
}
```

I am expecting string "That big zip file successfully parsed." as body get return instead of null? Any clue? Please help!

Comment: Remove `@Async` from your controller that has a whole different purpose.

Comment: Same issue, did you solve this or are you still stuck?

Comment: Same issue, anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I found out that in my case the `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` was causing the fault. This is what I did in my rest method to avoid the empty body:

```
ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.disableContentCaching(request);
```